# How to run a loop over names() of a data frame to create new data frames in R?

Tags: for-loop, sapply

I have a dataset called 'active' that has columns 'mh', 'dl', 'rj', and 'date' . I want to run the following operation on it, but preferably on a loop. How can I do it?

```
mh1 <- cbind.data.frame(active$mh, active$date) 
names(mh1) <- c('cases', 'date')
mh1$date <- dmy(mh1$date)

dl1 <- cbind.data.frame(active$dl, active$date) 
names(dl1) <- c('cases', 'date')
dl1$date <- dmy(dl1$date)

rj1 <- cbind.data.frame(active$rj, active$date) 
names(rj1) <- c('cases', 'date')
rj1$date <- dmy(rj1$date)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a neat solution here and given below. First of all, though, you should avoid redundant code via `active$date <- dmy(active$date)`. It keeps the format for all further subsetting.

The code for the original problem is as follows. Note that the code is so general that you can have more than the three columns `mh`, `rj` and `dl`, e.g. 100 columns, as long as the `data.frame` has in the last column that data you want to bind the other columns with.

**Data**

```
> active <- data.frame(mh = c(1, 2), dl = c(3, 4), 
                       rj = c(4, 5), date = c("31/12/2020", "30/12/2020"))
> active
  mh dl rj       date
1  1  3  4 31/12/2020
2  2  4  5 30/12/2020
```

**Code**

```
df_list <- lapply(1:(nrow(expand.grid(1:(ncol(active) - 1), ncol(active)))), 
                  function(x) active[, unlist(expand.grid(1:(ncol(active) - 1),   
                              ncol(active))[x,])]) %>% 
           lapply(., function(x){names(x) <- c("Cases", "Date"); x})
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
  Cases       Date
1     1 31/12/2020
2     2 30/12/2020

[[2]]
  Cases       Date
1     3 31/12/2020
2     4 30/12/2020

[[3]]
  Cases       Date
1     4 31/12/2020
2     5 30/12/2020
```